# Recreate localDiskDb.db in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

So I deleted the file .tmp/localDiskDb.db manually and now when Sails generates it on start its empty, Is there a way to make Sails to recreate it based on my models?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, that file contains only your models' *instances*, i.e. your actual data. To make it have some data, just create some instances of your models and save them into the file database.

Comment: the file is empty and I have models.

Comment: You need to save some model instances into your file database. I have reworded the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `./tmp/localDisk.db` removes your data. I wouldn't actually use the default `sails-disk` as my adapter, if I were you. You should use a better DB (e.g mysql, sqlite, mongodb etc) that prevents issues like these. `localDisk.db` is literally a text file not isolated from your dev environment. you can see how this would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

use fixtures in your config/bootstrap to import "dummy" Data on Startup